# How to drag and reorder content in angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have 5 different content. I want to drag and reorder it in the same row.. How can I do this in angular 2,4,5 or 6. If anybody know please help me to do this.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cc9ztn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Why are you mixing angularjs 1.X with the new angular?

Comment: That is angular only. Not angular js. Please check the code once.

Comment: I did. You have a complete HTML in the app component template, there is a script tag showing angular.module(....).controller(...). That is angularjs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This library contains all drag and drop features [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula), and this is the [demo](https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/).

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7b6iye)

Comment: I tried this already. Please look at my stackblitz example. Exactly that is requirement. Is this possible to do on this please?

Comment: why do you mix angular 1 with angular ??

Comment: I want only in angular. If you remove angular 1 code also it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much @Muhammad Albarmawi. I exactly used the same code. But for me it is coming one by one. Re-ordering content coming down. I don't know what is the issue. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I use this package, it is useful, good theme(especially with Material)
[here the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dnd)

[here Demo](http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/dnd)

Answer (score 0):

The best package I was able to find and finally solve my task is https://github.com/SortableJS/ngx-sortablejs

[Demo](https://sortablejs.github.io/ngx-sortablejs/sortable-array)